# How to add item to listbox when infected?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm trying to make an MD5 Anti-Virus program. It's one thing I need help with. I want the "selectedFile" to get added to listbox1 if it's infected.
Here is my code:

This makes me open the file

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        ofd.Filter = "Files | *";
        if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            md5box.Text = GetMD5FromFile(ofd.FileName);
           
        }
```

This is the scan button:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var md5signatures = File.ReadAllLines(@".\AntiChecker.txt");
        if (md5signatures.Contains(md5box.Text))
        {
            Status.Text = "Infected!";
            Status.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            listBox1.Items.Add(Here i want the file that ive browsed to add)
            
        }

        else
        {
            Status.Text = "Clean!";
            Status.ForeColor = Color.Green;
        }           
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First save the filename of the selected file from the file dialog by for example using an attribute in the class.

```
private string selectedFileName; //attribute in the class

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
   ofd.Filter = "Files | *";
   if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   {
       md5box.Text = GetMD5FromFile(ofd.FileName);      
       selectedFileName = ofd.FileName; //set to the path of the opened file   
   }
}
```

You can then add the saved file path to the `ListBox` simply by doing `listbox1.Items.Add(selectedFileName)` in `button2_Click`.

Comment: Isn't "AntiChecker.txt" the file containing the checksums? I don't think that's the file the OP wanted to add to the listbox.

Comment: Thank you, ive tried so many different options. This one works perfectly! Would have +1 but can't since my reputation isn't good enough. But ill give you a + through this comment.

Comment: One more thing, i would like to add a progressbar now and i probably need to make a string or something first. Then i want the progressbar to progress where it reads the lines on the text document. Do you know the code for that?

Comment: If the code in my answer solves your problem you should accept the answer, just press the check under the voting section of my answer. I can probably help you with the `ProgressBar` but for structure you should make a new question for that problem. On Stack Overflow if you need additional functionality you should always make a new question. Make a new question and I can try and help you there, just let me know when you created it. :)

Comment: Thank you. I'm new to this forum so I'm not so used to things. Thank you for clearing it up :D

Comment: I've created a new thread (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62813908/progressbar-when-reading-the-txt-document-file)